# VSCodeの「更新を確認」メニューが表示されない。

Tags: vscode

VSCodeの設定でアプリケーション-更新のUpdate: Modeは、defaultに設定しています。
更新があれば、自動で通知される設定ですが、しばらく通知がないので、手動で確認しようとしたところ以前は、表示されていた「更新の確認」がなくなっていました。
確認したのは、左下の設定メニューとヘルプメニューです。（下記メニュースクリーンショット参照）

VSCodeのヘルプ-バージョン情報は、下記の通り1.79.2を使用しています。
最新版は、Version 1.84が公開されています。

```
バージョン: 1.79.2 (user setup)
コミット: 695af097c7bd098fbf017ce3ac85e09bbc5dda06
 日付: 2023-06-14T08:57:04.379Z
Electron: 22.5.7
Chromium: 108.0.5359.215
Node.js: 16.17.1
V8: 10.8.168.25-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
```

### メニュースクリーンショット

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3):

こちら英語サイトの記事で：
[Why is "Check for Update" missing and updating if VS Code is started in Admin mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77100837/9014308)
マイナス投票の付いた回答ですが、試したところではそのとおりの内容なので、質問の状況に合っていると思われます。

VSCodeのマニュアル [Visual Studio Code on Windows](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/windows) に以下の注意が書かれています。

> > **Note:** When running VS Code as Administrator in a user setup installation, updates will be disabled.

`ユーザー セットアップ インストールした VS Code を管理者として実行すると、更新は無効になります。`とのことで、実際にそのように実行すると以下のトーストメッセージが表示され、メニューには「更新を確認...」がありませんでした。
[image: VSCodeトースト表示]

ということで、「管理者として実行」ではなくユーザーとしてのモードで起動すればメニューに「更新を確認...」が表示されて確認が実行できるようになるでしょう。

あるいはこちらの記事のように最新版(or好みの指定版数)のインストーラーを入手してインストールすれば、その版になるでしょう。
[Visual Studio Code(vscode) 「更新の確認」が出現しない場合のアップデート方法](https://qiita.com/renkuuuuuunn/items/2b1faf2c601dace06d3e)

Answer (score 1):

"vscode check for updates" で検索すると、例えば以下のページがヒットします。

[After July 2022 (version 1.70) release update option is missing in vs code settings button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73578938/2322778)

> This option is available on **System Installer** not <s>**User Installer**</s>.

Answer (score 0):

ありがとうございました。

下記のUser Installerをダウンロードして再インストールでバージョンアップはできましたが、更新メニューは表示されませんでした。（下記ログ参照）

上書インストールだけだと、改善されませんでした。

されないようなので、アンインストールしてからインストールしてみます。

### ログ

User Installをダウンロード

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

インストール時に下記のようなメッセージが表示されました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

1.84にバージョンアップされましたが、起動時に下記のようなエラーが出ました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

コントロールパネルから`Microsoft Visual Studio Code(User)`をアンインストールして、System Installerをダウンロードしてインストールしたところ`更新の確認...`が使用できるようになりました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: VSCodeを管理者モードで起動している意識はなかったのですが、Windowsにログインする際に使っているユーザがAdministrator権限を持っていたことが原因のようです。